# Sort by array's last element mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, spring-boot

I was trying to sort documents by last interaction. meta_data.access_times is an array that update every time when user interacts and new date object append to the last element of the array. Is there any way to sort by array's last element?

Attempt 1 :

```
private Aggregation makeQuery(String userId) {
     return newAggregation(
          match(Criteria.where("user_id").is(userId)),
          sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "$meta_data.access_times"),
          group(Fields.fields().and("first_name", "$meta_data.user_data.first_name").and("last_name", "$meta_data.user_data.last_name").and("profile_pic", "$meta_data.user_data.profile_pic").and("user_id", "$user_id").and("access_times", "$meta_data.access_times"))
      );
    }
```

Attempt 2 :

```
 private Aggregation makeQuery(String userId) {
        return newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("user_id").is(user_id)),
            group(Fields.fields().and("first_name", "$meta_data.user_data.first_name").and("last_name", "$meta_data.user_data.last_name").and("profile_pic", "$meta_data.user_data.profile_pic").and("user_id", "$user_id")).max("$meta_data.access_times").as("access_time"),
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "access_time")
        );
    }
```

sample meta_data array in document

```
"meta_data" : { "access_times" : [ 
            ISODate("2017-06-20T14:04:14.910Z"), 
            ISODate("2017-06-22T06:27:32.210Z"), 
            ISODate("2017-06-22T06:27:35.326Z"), 
            ISODate("2017-06-22T06:31:28.048Z"), 
            ISODate("2017-06-22T06:36:19.664Z"), 
            ISODate("2017-06-22T06:37:00.164Z")
        ] }
```

Comment: Well we seem to be missing any representation of what your document actually looks like. Care to share it with us?

Comment: @NeilLunn updated

Comment: So the "last" is always appended and therefore the "latest"? Normally is but just checking.

Comment: @NeilLunn yeah!

Comment: What do you expect as output? That `group` is throwing me as it's not clear what to expect. Mostly since it's not valid. How about showing whole documents ( just 2 or 3 ) and what you expect to get as your query result. That would be clearer to interpret than your query attempt. The date part I already understand.

Comment: What I do is I sort documents by last interaction time and group particular fields ("first_name", "last_name", "profile_pic", "user_id", "labels", "access_times") those are contain in every document. every user has particular document.

Comment: So what is the problem that you are facing with first attempt ? Can you add some documents that can recreate the scenario for us ? Also what is your expected output ?

Comment: @veeram not sorted properly. If new document created it comes to first in results, but if old document's array updated it not comes to first in results. Expected output is sorted documents by last interaction. Array's last element is the user's last interaction.

Comment: I think I understood the problem but first query should work as expected. So you really need to add some documents to the question that when run with query can demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solves the problem by using $unwind operation.

```
 private Aggregation makeQuery(String userId) {
        return newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("user_id").is(userId)),
            unwind("$meta_data.access_times"),
            group(Fields.fields().and("first_name", "$meta_data.user_data.first_name").and("last_name", "$meta_data.user_data.last_name").and("profile_pic", "$meta_data.user_data.profile_pic").and("user_id", "$user_id")).max("$meta_data.access_times").as("access_time"),
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "access_time")
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**When you don't know if the element to Push is Ordered** or not (for example, an User that is pushing him Score...) you can use $push and $sort in order to have an ordered array, then you can just sort by "find({userId:yourUseId}.sort("metadata.access_time.0":-1).

This solution suppose your array are Ordered with $sort at creation/update time: [LINK](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort)

**When you are sure that the Push don't need a sort** (for example you are Pushing a Access_Date for that User) you can $push and void $sort by using $operator (tnx Erdenezul). [LINK](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/)

In theory you don't need an Index on the Array "access_time" if the find() is fetching only fews documents. Otherwise you can just add an index with {"metadata.access_time.0": -1}.

Good Luck!

Comment: Add latest access into 0th element with push position 0 would be nice

Comment: @Erdenezul do you think is not a viable solution?

Comment: in order to avoid sort, pushing latest element at index 0 is more efficient.

Comment: @Erdenezul oh you are right, $position can be used but I have just posted a general solution that work for any scenario.

Comment: could you revise your answer with my idea, then I can vote up your answer

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/ this link would help

Comment: @Erdenezul let me know